# Can many threads send over a single ØMQ socket when mutexes are used?

Tags: c, concurrency, mutex, zeromq

The documentation of ØMQ mentions:

> Individual ØMQ sockets are not thread safe except in the case where full memory barriers are issued when migrating a socket from one thread to another.

What exactly is meant by "full memory barriers?" Can I have multiple threads send over the same ØMQ socket if I synchronize this with mutexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acquiring a mutex implies a memory barrier. This basically means that write operations must not be reordered in a way that they cross this operation. Summary: Yes, use a mutex to protect access to the ZMQ socket and you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

As Ulrich has said, yes you can synchronise access to a single thread using mutexes, but really, why would you want to do that?

It's normally considered good practice to only access a socket from a single thread, and synchronise between threads using messages. Something like this:

```
Worker thread 1
                \
Worker thread 2 - >  Control thread -> msg out
                /
Worker thread 3
```

where only the control thread can send messages directly over the socket. Messages from the worker threads would be sent to the control thread over an inproc zmq socket that you would create. The control thread would process just one message at a time which avoids the need for the mutexes, provided the workers have no shared state.

Message based designs are easier to implement and debug, and much easier to maintain than designs using mutexes. If you can change the design to do that, I'd advise doing so.

Comment: Because I am using Python's logging library, which works using mutexes. I am aware of inproc sockets, but I cannot use them here.

Comment: @rightfold as John depicted, **ZeroMQ** explicitly recommends to stop thinking in terms of blocking ( mutex, semaphore, et al) and to avoid sharing. The smart design approach is to arrange Signalling & Control layers atop of the "just message passing" layer, so as to achive what your respective design-needs dictate. **Introducing any blocking into a non-blocking world sounds as strange as oxymoron does.** It may have their special "beauty" however the real-life talk makes indeed a very few uses for 'em. If your goal was to re-use the blocking as a side-effect, better design your own ZMQ SIG-s.

Comment: This is a very good point, cooperating is better than competing for a resource.

Comment: @user3666197 if you want to patch the Python logging library then I'm totally in for that.

Comment: I don't get why the use of the Python logging library is causing such difficulty. What you need is a thread/process dedicated to handling logs, and it alone talks to the Python logger thus avoiding the need for mutexes. All other threads pass logging messages to the logging thread via ZeroMQ messages. Et Voila.